# Plotting mass spectrum of states

Tags: plotting

How can I obtain the following plot via Mathematica? I have my own data but I couldn't have obtained the plot. Thank you for your help[image: Mass spectrum]

Comment: {4978,5148} for 0^+, {4976,5173,5182} for 1^+, {5188} for 2^+

Answer (score 4):

Here's an attempt made by forcing `BarChart` into service with a custom `ChartElementFunction` to generate just a line:

```
ClearAll[cef]
cef[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, val_, __] := 
 {
   Line[{{xmin, ymax}, {xmax, ymax}}],
   Inset[Style[val, 16], {Mean[{xmin, xmax}], ymax + 15}]
 }

BarChart[
 {Style[{4978, 5148}, Red],
  Style[{4976, 5173, 5182}, Blue], 
  Style[{5188}, Purple]},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {4950, 5310}},
 ChartElementFunction -> cef,
 ChartLayout -> "Overlapped",
 ChartLabels -> {{}, 
   MapThread[
    Style[#1, 16, #2] &, {{"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(0\), \(+\)]\)", 
      "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(1\), \(+\)]\)", 
      "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(2\), \(+\)]\)"}, {Red, Blue, 
      Purple}}], {"", "", ""}},
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}},
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 16],
 FrameLabel -> {None, Style["Mass (MeV)", 18, Black]},
 AspectRatio -> 1
]
```

[image: a similar plot to OP, but still trouble with text labels]

As you can see, the text labels are not quite right, because intelligent placement would be needed for the central data set. I would recommend actually placing them by hand instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. How would it possible to place by hand?